# Proof that random variables in a joint distribution are independent

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I know the rule that states the $X$ & $Y$ are independent iff $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$

let's assume you have the following joint distribution:

$f(x,y) = 6/5(x+y^2)$ where $0<=x<=1$ and $0<=y<=1$

I integrated the joint distribution to get the following marginal distributions:

$f(x)=6x/5 +2/5$

$f(y)=6y^2/5+3/5$

It seems obvious to me that X and Y should be independent since the ranges don't depend on each other, and either could be any value at any time. I don't understand why then that I can't prove that $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$

this is what I have so far:

$f(x)f(y) = (6x/5 +2/5)(6y^2/5+3/5)$

$=(18x + 36xy^2 + 12y^2 + 6)/25$

Comment: Because they are not independent.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how are they not independent if their ranges don't depend on each other? they both can be of any value between 0 and 1 at any time, regardless of the value of the other RV.

Comment: That is not enough for independence. If you wish, calculate $\Pr(X\le 1/2)$ and also $\Pr(Y\le 1/2)$. Probably (I have not checked) the product will be different from $\Pr(X\le 1/2\cap Y\le 1/2)$.

Comment: Or more simply check whether $f_X(1/2)f_Y(1/2)=f_{X,Y}(1/2,1/2)$.